# Floats in Arrays not being compared correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, selenium, selenium-ide

I am trying to compare values in an Array (Dynamically added from a website), using Selenium-IDE to do this comparison.

For some reason they are still being compared using string logic - so 58 > 105 (Because 5 > 1)

Below is my code extract that I know to be faulty

```
<tr>
    <td>storeEval</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>i</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>while</td>
    <td>storedVars['i'] &lt; storedVars['parcTotal']</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>storeEval</td>
    <td>jQuery('article.parcarticle').eq(${i}).attr('id')</td>
    <td>articleID</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>storeText</td>
    <td>css=#${articleID} .table-container tr:nth-child(2) .tbl-price .price</td>
    <td>firstParcCost</td>
</tr>
<!--Remove all Commas and Currency Symbol-->
<tr>
    <td>echo</td>
    <td>${firstParcCost}</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>storeEval</td>
    <td>javascript{storedVars['firstParcCost'].replace(&quot;,&quot;,&quot;&quot;).substring(1)}</td>
    <td>firstParcCost</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>storeEval</td>
    <td>javascript{parseInt(storedVars['firstParcCost'])}</td>
    <td>firstParcCost</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>echo</td>
    <td>${firstParcCost}</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>push</td>
    <td>javascript{storedVars['firstParcCost']}</td>
    <td>firstParcCostArray</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>echo</td>
    <td>${firstParcCostArray}</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>gotoIf</td>
    <td>storedVars['i']==0</td>
    <td>zeroSkip</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>echo</td>
    <td>javascript{storedVars['firstParcCostArray'][(storedVars['i'])-1] + &quot; is bigger than &quot; + storedVars['firstParcCostArray'][(storedVars['i'])]}</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>assertEval</td>
    <td>storedVars['firstParcCostArray'][(storedVars['i'])-1] &gt;= storedVars['firstParcCostArray'][(storedVars['i'])]</td>
    <td>true</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>label</td>
    <td>zeroSkip</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>storeEval</td>
    <td>${i}+1</td>
    <td>i</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>endWhile</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: What ... why is the code in an HTML table?

Comment: @Pointy Selenium-IDE records user interactions with web pages and stores these interactions as some sort of table of commands. Users often export the commands as an HTML table when they need to discuss the commands with others. I don't know whether getting an HTML table from Selenium-IDE is as good as it gets or if there's something that the majority of its users are ignoring. It is a rather common occurrence to see Selenium-IDE questions include such tables.

Comment: @Louis well that clears up the mystery, but it leaves the question in the same unfortunate state.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a work-around which deals with a lack of JS knowledge.

I've moved the parseFloat to the Assertion, and that has appeared to fix things. I've been told that parseFloat only treats it as a float temporarily, and then reverts back to its old data-type